# Java Android why delete a images does't delete

Tags: java, android

I want to delete a images older than N days I do this :

```
    File f = new File("/sdcard/Foto+");
            File[] files1 = f.listFiles();

public void deleteFilesOlderThanNdays(File[] listFiles) {
    long purgeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - (Config.daysBackToDelete * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    for (File listFile : listFiles) {
        if (listFile.lastModified() < purgeTime) {
            listFile.delete();
            if(listFile.exists()){
                try {
                    listFile.getCanonicalFile().delete();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(listFile.exists()){
                    getApplicationContext().deleteFile(listFile.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in this case when I try do this a images doesn't remove from this folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete file from MediaStore as well. Use the following method

```
deleteFileFromMediaStore(getContext().getContentResolver(), listFile);
```

Just call above method after deleting your image.

```
public static void deleteFileFromMediaStore(final ContentResolver contentResolver, final File file) {
        String canonicalPath;
        try {
            canonicalPath = file.getCanonicalPath();

            final Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
            final int result = contentResolver.delete(uri,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{canonicalPath});
            if (result == 0) {
                final String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                if (!absolutePath.equals(canonicalPath)) {
                    contentResolver.delete(uri,
                            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{absolutePath});
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            canonicalPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```